# Is Pascal's law applicable in a very large enclosed ocean?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[Pascal's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_law) states that pressure is transmitted undiminished in an enclosed static fluid. Is this law applicable, say, We apply it to a small scale so molecules push each other to transmit the pressure to the whole fluid say water so what about in a very large enclosed ocean could molecules push all the way? and what is the percentage of the lost pressure?

Comment: Yes..any enclosed fluid.

Comment: For an ocean, it's going to be hard to reach the limit of a "static fluid".

Comment: @BowlOfRed What's the limit of static fluid?

Comment: It means that the law is only valid when the fluid is stationary.  The closer you get to it, the less the deviation from the ideal.  A large body like an ocean will have currents and waves.  These will cause significant pressure deviations from what you might expect if you assumed a static fluid.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I'm just assuming that we have an imaginary situation of an enclosed ocean so no waves are there and it's static like a very huge hydraulic press

Comment: Then the law will hold.  Why would you expect pressure loss?  Where would the loss be seen?

Comment: @BowlOfRed I expect that because the pressure has to travel across a very huge distance and so I expect the pressure would be lost at the other end of the ocean opposite to the pressure, it may be a very little loss or significant loss so my question is about how much is this loss.

Comment: I feel like no one pointed out that Pascal's Law is for "confined incompressible fluids" of which an ocean is not.  Although compression is low, a real scenario will not be the exact same as the idealized one in Pascals Law (this all depends on your acceptable amount of pressure variation between Pascals Law and real life).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works fine.

Pressure loss is generally associated with restrictions to flow.  But when there is no flow, no such loss occurs.

Assume you are in the (again, static) ocean at a particular depth.  If there were more pressure from one side than the other, then the pressure difference would accelerate some of the fluid and cause flow.  The redistribution would decrease the pressure difference.  Once the fluid stopped moving, the pressure would once again be identical.

In a huge fluid, this redistribution will take much longer than in a small tank.  But given sufficient time and stability, it would happen.